# Need help to identify existing siding

Tags: siding

I need to replace a large section of siding due to water damage.

I can't seem to find this siding at any of the box stores.

The panels are 11" and have 2 5" cedar planks molded into them. I believe they are mdf.

More pictures here
https://imgur.io/gallery/bZMlImC

[image: siding]

Comment: Check with the local siding companies.  Big box usually only carries what is popular at the time.

Comment: There's no requirement to replace it with identical siding. You can replace it with a different type that looks the same (or similar enough that you're happy with the appearance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased stuff like that for a job 5 years ago. It’s less Masonite and more low density particleboard. As such, it’s not a great material for siding — you’d get more durability if you replaced the entire wall with a cement board. (The economics would depend on what proportion is damaged.)

If you need just a bit, take a sample around to your local lumberyards. Don’t even bother with the big box stores. Let them deliver, whatever the price, as it’s floppy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Masonite siding.

After lawsuits the manufacturer discontinued producing it in 2001.

You may be able to find something similar in a Hardie plank or other cement based board.